# Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

So I'm brand new to PHP and am building a RPSLS implementation, just to be executed in the command line. I have a semi-working implementation but have two concerns.

1) The code below doesn't seem to be hitting the else condition when player 2 beats player one, and I can't identify why?

2) This is an incredibly repetitive set of conditionals. What would be a more efficient implementation? I'd really like to understand how to make this better.

Thanks

```
<?php

// Assign moves to integers (1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3 = Scissors, 4 = Lizard, 5 = Spock)
echo 'Welcome to Rock, Paper Scissors, Lizard, Spock';
echo "\n";

// Randomize Moves
$player1 = rand(1, 5);
$player2 = rand(1, 5);

// Declare wins
$rock_wins = array(3, 4);
$paper_wins = array(1, 5);
$scissors_wins = array(2, 4);
$lizard_wins = array(5, 2);
$spock_wins = array(3, 1);

// Conditional logic for wins
if ($player1 == $player2) {
    echo "Tie.";
    echo "\n";
} elseif ($player1 == 1) {
        if (in_array($player2, $rock_wins)) {
            echo "Player 1 wins";
            echo "\n";
        }
} elseif ($player1 == 2) {
    if (in_array($player2, $paper_wins)) {
            echo "Player 1 wins";
            echo "\n";
        }
} elseif ($player1 == 3) {
    if (in_array($player2, $scissors_wins)) {
            echo "Player 1 wins";
            echo "\n";
        }
}
elseif ($player1 == 4) {
    if (in_array($player2, $lizard_wins)) {
            echo "Player 1 wins";
            echo "\n";
        }
}
elseif ($player1 == 5) {
    if (in_array($player2, $spock_wins)) {
            echo "Player 1 wins";
            echo "\n";
        }
} else {
    echo "Player 2 wins";
}

?>
```

Comment: since there's only 5 choices, just set a 5x5 array and put a win/lose/tie value in each position. e.g. -1, 0, 1. then you're down to a simple array lookup to get the game's state.

Comment: What I would do is:
$messages = array("Player 1 wins", "Player 2 wins", "Draw");
print($messages[rand(0, count($messages) - 1)]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could encode the logic in a 2-dimensional array:

```
<?php
$play = function ($player1, $player2) {
    $rock = 1;
    $paper = 2;
    $scissors = 3;
    $lizard = 4;
    $spock = 5;
    $matches = array(
        $rock => array($scissor, $lizard),
        $paper => array($rock, $spock),
        $scissors => array($paper, $lizard),
        $lizard => array($spock, $paper),
        $spock => array($scissor, $rock),
    );

    return in_array($player2, $matches[$player1]);
};

// Assign moves to integers (1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3 = Scissors, 4 = Lizard, 5 = Spock)
echo 'Welcome to Rock, Paper Scissors, Lizard, Spock';
echo "\n";

// Randomize Moves
$player1 = rand(1, 5);
$player2 = rand(1, 5);

if ($player1 == $player2) {
    echo "Draw!\n";
} else if (Game::play($player1, $player2)) {
    echo "Player 1 wins\n";
} else {
    echo "Player 2 wins\n";
}
```

Obviously the improvement are endless:

- you could replace the function with a closure (either  a class with a `play` method or a nested function inside a factory function) on the 2d-array so you're not instantiating it at each call
- you could use constants instead of variables for the values of rock, paper, etc.
- you *should* test that the inputs are within the set of valid values, and so on.

  ```
  <?php
  class Game {
      const ROCK = 1;
      const PAPER = 2;
      const SCISSORS = 3;
      const LIZARD = 4;
      const SPOCK = 5;
      const MATCHES = array(
          self::ROCK => array(self::SCISSOR, self::LIZARD),
          self::PAPER => array(self::ROCK, self::SPOCK),
          self::SCISSORS => array(self::PAPER, self::LIZARD),
          self::LIZARD => array(self::SPOCK, self::PAPER),
          self::SPOCK => array(self::SCISSOR, self::ROCK),
      );

      public static function play($player1, $player2) {
          if (!self::isValid($player1) || !self::isValid($player2)) {
              throw new Exception('Invalid input!');
          }
          return in_array($player2, self::matches[$player1]);
      }

      public static function isValid($num) {
          return array_key_exists(self::MATCHES, $num);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Upvote.  Looks clean and easy.  I like the way you return true or false but the one problem I see is the fact that you have to check if `$player1` and `$player2` are equal outside of the function.  Just brainstorming here but maybe you should check if they are equal in the function and return 0 for a  draw, 1 for if player1 wins and 2 if player 2 wins.  So treat the return as a winner.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc B said in the comments, there are better ways to do this problem, but for your situation, the reason why Player 2 will never win is because you have it as an else condition based on what `$player1` is equal to.  You should have the else based on if `$player2` is in the array.

Just strip the inside if constraints away and you have:

```
if ($player1 == $player2) {
    echo "Tie.";
    echo "\n";
} elseif ($player1 == 1) {

} elseif ($player1 == 2) {

} elseif ($player1 == 3) {

} elseif ($player1 == 4) {

} elseif ($player1 == 5) {

} else {
    echo "Player 2 wins";
}
```

The only possible way Player 2 would win in this is if `$player2` is not equal to `$player1` and `$player1` is not equal to `1` through `5`.

So if you set `$player1` to `6`, Player 2 would "win" but this doesn't make sense in the context of the game.

Answer (score 0):

You say you're new to php and I'm guessing you are relatively new to programming. With this in mind I would concentrate on some of the basic principles.

So to answer your question 2), here are a few things that might be worth considering:

- Add good comments to your code - here it would be helpful to
  document the rules of RPSLS. I had to look up the rules for this
  game, and it looks like at least one person has misundertood the
  rules. I find that ways of approaching a problem often become clear
  when I write the comments.
- Use constants for values that are not going to change - i.e. use
  ROCK instead of 1, PAPER instead of 2 etc. Other languages have
  enumerations for this purpose but in php you can use the "define" to
  associate each named constant with its value. This should make the program much easier to read, and make it easier to pick up any errors - if you try to use a constant that hasn't been defined you will get a warning.
- If possible, the program structure should match the "logical" way of
  thinking about the problem. For example the essence of the program
  is as follows:

  ```
  if (player 1 beats player 2) {
      echo "Player 1 wins\n";
  }
  elseif (player 2 beats player 1) {
      echo "Player 2 wins\n";
  }
  else {
      echo "Tie.";
  }
  ```

Pulling these together, here is an alternative way of doing what you want:

```
<?php

// As we'll use these as array indices, we'll start at 0 
define ('ROCK', 0); 
define ('PAPER', 1); 
define ('SCISSORS', 2); 
define ('LIZARD', 3); 
define ('SPOCK', 4); 

/* 
    A reasonable place to document the rules ....
*/
$winning_conditions = array();
$winning_conditions[ROCK] = array(SCISSORS, LIZARD);
$winning_conditions[SCISSORS] = array(PAPER, LIZARD);
$winning_conditions[LIZARD] = array(SPOCK, PAPER);
$winning_conditions[SPOCK] = array(SCISSORS, ROCK);
$winning_conditions[PAPER] = array(ROCK, SPOCK);

// Randomize Moves
$player1 = rand(0, 4);
$player2 = rand(0, 4);

if (in_array($player2, $winning_conditions[$player1]) {
    echo "Player 1 wins\n";
}
elseif (in_array($player1, $winning_conditions[$player2]) {
    echo "Player 2 wins\n";
}
else {
    echo "Tie.\n";
}

?>
```

And with a few additions (perhaps using php associative arrays) it should be possible to enhance the output to something like:

```
Player 2 wins (Lizard poisons Spock)
```